# How to keep relative positioned parent in document flow?

Tags: html, css, css-position, overlay, absolute

I have two sections, the 1st section is using position relative and contains 2 absolute children inside with the children being overlayed. The 2nd section contains a title.

I would like to keep the 1st section with position relative in flow so the 2nd section appears below. I understand position absolute takes elements outside of the document flow but is this the case even with a relative parent?

How can i keep the parent in flow?

```css
.parent {
    position: relative;
}
.child  {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.child1 {
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 1;
}

.child2 {
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child child1">block1</div>
  <div class="child child2">block2</div>
</div>

<div class="text">
  <h1>block below</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the parent element dimensions, so its children can take place. As the absolute-positioned children are taken off the regular flow, it means that the parent div doesn't contain anything, thus it "disappears". I.e.:

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: Wheat;
}
```

And the snippet:

```css
.parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: Wheat;
}
.child  {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.child1 {
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 1;
}

.child2 {
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child child1">block1</div>
  <div class="child child2">block2</div>
</div>

<div class="text">
  <h1>block below</h1>
</div>
```

If you need the parent div not to exit the normal flow, then it should be static:

```css
.child  {
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.child1 {
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}

.child2 {
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child child1">block1</div>
  <div class="child child2">block2</div>
</div>

<div class="text">
  <h1>block below</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I see, thanks for your response, my issue with this is that i can't use px for height as my site is responsive, can it only working with a fixed value?

Comment: Sure, you only need to set the parent's positioning to static (so, no position at all), and then it will work, as it will get back into the flow. I'm updating the code snippet.

Comment: I tried implementing this on my project however the first child still moves the parent out of the flow, I am trying to implement it with tabs

Comment: Sorry it didn't work! If the parent div has to be relative-position due to the layout architecture, you could always use a simple hack: besides the two current children divs, add a third one with the minimum possible content  (i.e., a single dot) and set its `visibility` to `hidden`, or simply the text `color` to `transparent`, or `rgba(255,255,255,0)`. It will be actual content so the parent div won't vanish anymore. Also be sure to add the `aria-hidden="true"` attribute to grant it won't be taken into account when using screen readers. This is clearly an inelegant solution but it could help.